# Can't make MS webView2 control work on user machines

Tags: webview2

HELP! I've been programming with Visual Studio vb for years, but I'm trying to use the new WebView2 control in my desktop apps, and I'm afraid I'm not having much luck.

I'm trying to use the fixed version of the WebView2 runtime rather than the evergreen version. I've downloaded the fixed version files to my development machine. I've included them in my test project. When I publish and install my test project on a PC, I'm able to see the directory containing all the WebView2 .dll files inside the same directory where my program is installed. Then, according to what I've read elsewhere, I use the following code to point my WebView2 control to those .dlls:

```
   Dim strPathToFiles As String

   strPathToFiles = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString & "\SubdirectoryWhereDLLsAre\"

   Dim env = Await Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(strPathToFiles)

   Await Me.WebView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env)

   Me.WebView21.Source = New Uri("https://www.google.com/")
```

In short, it doesn't work. I get a 'System cannot find the file specified' error. I've been fighting this for 2 weeks. The MS online docs haven't helped. I'm using the .net Framework 4.8. Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you so much for any help. I'm completely stuck at this point.

Comment: From the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#details-about-the-fixed-version-runtime-distribution-mode : "Verify that the bin\**designated architecture**\Release folder has a matching FixedRuntime\(version number) folder with the runtime files in it."

Comment: Poul. Thank you for your help. I'm afraid it didn't fix anything. I'm still doing something wrong. But there's no need to offer any further help. I initially went with the fixed runtime because it seemed to offer some minor advantages over the evergreen. Now this experience has taught me that the fixed version is going to be a huge hassle for those minor advantages. So I just switched to the evergreen, and now everything works perfectly. Live and learn. Now I'm just going to use the evergreen. Thanks again for all your help.